# how to make straight edges smoother

Tags: modeling, edges

Im creating low poly game assets, but i have a problem with my models. I want to make the edges of my object look smoother like the one in the photo below, before and after (this is not mine, its from a tutorial on art station)

[image]

anyway... if i want to make the edges smoother i have to add subdivide and then subdivision modifier etc, but that adds a lot of vertices, which is not really useful when working on low poly as you may know. the other way to smooth out the edges is to use the sculpting tools, but that also adds extra vertices to my mesh.

I want to achieve smooth edges without having to add anything extra, or at least minimum as possible.  any ideas??

Comment: Have you tried beveling the edges?

Comment: Good call, it might work. How can i do it?

Comment: Either by adding a bevel modifier or editing the mesh using the [bevel tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JSvGts95S7A).

Comment: thanks bro it reallyhelps

Comment: you can bevel, then create a normal map from the beveled version that you'll use on the low-poly, this way you have zero additional vertex

Comment: So I only make a normal map and it will be ok ?

Comment: yes, it needs a bit of explanation though, I'll try

Comment: please do, thankyou. i know some things about normal maps but only for texturing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least 2 methods. The one you'll choose will depend on the amount of vertices you want and the time you want to spend on each object.

**First method, bevels (faster but more vertices):** You can select your object, go in *Edit* mode, select the angles you want, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel, and set the bevel values in the operator panel. If the amount of *Segments* is low you can keep a rather low-poly version.

**Second method, bevels + normal map (longer but no additional vertices):** You can duplicate your object, bevel the copy, create a normal map from the beveled version, and use the normal map on the low-poly. This way you have zero additional vertex:

- Create your low-poly version.

[image]

- Duplicate it. Select the copy and in *Edit* mode, bevel the angles you want. Also, pump it up slightly with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (*Shrink Fatten* tool), keep pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> if you want to be more precise. Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.

[image]

- Bake the high-poly normals. To do so, first unwrap the low-poly (*Smart UV Project* mode), create a new black image in the UV Editor (*32 Bit Float* option activated I guess), give your low-poly a material with *Image Texture* > *Normal Map* > *Diffuse* > *Output*. Don't plug the *Image Texture* for the moment but switch it to *Non-Color Data* and load the image you've created before. Select the high poly object, then the low-poly, and in the *Render* > *Bake* panel, choose *Bake Type* > *Normal*, enable *Selected to Active*, click the *Bake* button. Set the *Ray Distance* at the right value, so that you have as less artefacts as possible. Anyway you'll necessary have some with this kind of geometry.

[image]

- Export the normal map, import it in an image editor software, try to remove as many artefacts as possible, don't try it to make it perfect though, reimport the image, load it in the *Image Texture* node, plug the *Image Texture* node into the *Normal* socket of the Diffuse. You can also bring some corrections on your normal map directly in the *3D View* / *Texture Paint* mode: Plug your *Image Texture* in the *Color* socket of the *Diffuse* to display it on the object, switch the 3D View to *Texture* shading, and use the *Clone* brush for example. When you're good, replug the *Image Texture* in the *Normal Map* node.

[image]

Comment: thanks so much bro